# Solution to slow connection to document storage

Tags: php, phpseclib, synology

I am using phpseclib and SFTP to allow users to upload documents from my website(hosted with godaddy) to a Synology home server.  When the user goes to a page where a list of their currently uploaded documents is displayed it takes 2-4 seconds before the page loads.

I would like to know some options to speed up this process.  One thought that I had was to store the list of the user's documents in my database so that the site does not have to query the home server to get a list for the user.  However, I worry about there being a discrepancy between what is in the database and what is on the home server.

Are there other smart ways to speed up the retrieval?  Would AJAX be an option?  Maybe load the rest of the page but use ajax to load the document list?

Comment: You're going across the internet, from a mediocre hosting provider to your house and back again with all of this data.  It's going to be slow.  Caching the index as you have proposed is about the only way to work around it.

Comment: I am ok with it taking a few seconds, but I would like the rest of the page to load and have a loading message where the document list might go.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to learn how to do this?

Comment: In that case, AJAX is what you are looking for.